# MarkLogic 8 - Corb pass arguments other than $URI

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-corb

So I have a file **uris.xqy** that gets the document URI's that I want to operate on in **corb**.

Then I have **docs.xqy** that brings in the $URI

       `declare variable $URI as xs:string external;`

And then I do some processing on that document.

Now I want to pass in a parameter to corb from the command line such that

`./ml ${Environment} corb --uris=/uris.xqy --modules=/docs.xqy --hello=world`

When I execute the command above I would have access to **hello** and it's contents **world** in **docs.xqy**.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is a Custom Property

```
PROCESS-MODULE.hello=world
```

The CORB2 wiki explains this at

https://github.com/marklogic/corb2/wiki/Other-Properties#custom-properties

> To use a custom property, it must be prepended with the Task name and
>   declared as an external variable in the XQuery.
>
> To pass a collection name to the PROCESS task use:
>
> `PROCESS-MODULE.collectionName=nameOfCollectionToUse`

Comment: Ughhh took me a little while to formulate my next question...if I am running corb through roxy it does not look like there is a way to pass in custom parameters.

https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/blob/10a0dc62a5b6aea1fcd9427d1cd21d1a9395150c/deploy/lib/Help.rb

So if I'm right, then...I need to figure out how to run corb directly (as in not through Roxy). This was all setup by consultants and I'm not sure how it all works yet.

Comment: Aha! I think I found it just now! Something like this:

java -server -cp .:marklogic-xcc-6.0.2.jar:marklogic-corb-2.1.2.jar com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager XCC-CONNECTION-URI [COLLECTION-NAME [XQUERY-MODULE [ THREAD-COUNT [ URIS-MODULE [ MODULE-ROOT [ MODULES-DATABASE [ INSTALL [ PROCESS-TASK [ PRE-BATCH-MODULE [ PRE-BATCH-TASK [ POST-XQUERY-MODULE [ POST-BATCH-TASK [ EXPORT-FILE-DIR [ EXPORT-FILE-NAME [ URIS-FILE ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

Comment: Yes, you'll have to run corb2 directly. if it helps you can add all of that to a properties files and just point corb2 to the properties file

Comment: A ticket has been opened against Roxy to add support for Corb2. Pull requests welcome.. https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/issues/521

Comment: If I have to pass an argument to URI-MODULE, in that case what to do. I tried --URIS-MODULE.ID=1, but this didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

With Roxy v1.7.4+, you can now specify any CoRB options, to include custom module inputs, using either the `--` or `-D` switches.

If you upgrade to Roxy [1.7.4.1](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/releases/tag/v1.7.4.1) (or later), you can send the value to the **docs.xqy** module external variable named "hello" by executing the following:

```
./ml ${Environment} corb --uris=/uris.xqy --modules=/docs.xqy --PROCESS-MODULE.hello=world
```

Comment: If I have to pass an argument to URI-MODULE, in that case what to do. I tried --URIS-MODULE.ID=1, but this didn't worked

Comment: That looks right. You could also try specifying as a System property using -DURIS-MODULE.ID=1. Double check your URIs module to ensure that the ID external variable is declared properly.

Comment: My bad, I declared it but passed empty hence returned external variable undefined. I made the necessary changes and working as expected now